# Using VM to backup MySQL database

Tags: mysql, virtual-machine

Is it correct to use a backup of a vm as a means of restoring a MySQL database?
Are there any dangers in doing this?
My own feeling is that a vm backup/snapshot is at the os not the db level and therefore may not backup the database in the correct way. Has anybody any advice on this?

Answer (score 3):

It's perfectly fine as long as you do one of two things:

- Either ensure consistency of the tables by either shutting down the database or using something like `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` while doing the snapshot (*you probably don't want to do this*)
- **Use a transactionally-safe storage engine** such as **InnoDB** (the default) for all tables that are likely to change around the time of the snapshot, and rely on its ability to recover from what looks like a crashed state, i.e. the copy of a running server.

Once you realise that taking a snapshot of a running VM and booting the snapshot on another machine looks just like pulling the plug on that server and rebooting it, your choice becomes relatively easy: Make sure the system can recover from pulling the plug, and it can recover from a VM snapshot backup.

Comment: Would you advise this as a long-term db backup solution in preference to a dedicated db backup tool like mysqldump for example? Also is there any risk of data corruption in regularly restoring the data in a crash-recovery way? Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: I wouldn't advise it as your primary backup solution. I know there are people doing it all the time, but even if it is 99% reliable (and I don't know that it is in your environment), that means 1 in every 100 backups is unreliable, and if you create a snapshot twice a day, it means you're exposed at least once every couple of months. That's why I say that it's fine as long as you're happy to rely on the (extraordinary) recovery feature of InnoDB. Snapshot backup has great benefits (it's fast and easy), but it's not as reliable as e.g. mysqldump, MySQL Enterprise Backup, or XtraBackup.

Answer (score 2):

Based on a recommendation from Jeff Hunter posted on the [VMWare blog](http://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2014/12/mysql-backup-with-vdp.html), the answer is **no, it's not safe to rely on the snapshots for MySQL backups**.  His recommendation is basically to dump the db through a separate process (and then allow the snapshot to copy the dump).